# \colorbox with Hebrew

Tags: color, framed, hebrew, right-to-left

When using a `\colorbox` (or derivates such as framed's `shadedbox`) with Hebrew and pdflatex, the color stack seems to get confused:

> pdfTeX warning: pdflatex: pop empty color page stack 0

and the output is wrong (black background color).

Is there a workaround for this issue? (I am aware that XeTeX/bidi works, but I want to know whether there is also some way in [pdf]latex)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 0}

\usepackage[hebrew]{babel}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{shadecolor}{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how you are using Latex or Lyx In hebrew? I tried to fix the problem after I moved from Lyx 2.2 to lyx 2.3, but I could not find a solution. what font packages are you using?

Comment: @Jneven I use DavidCLM, but please ask on lyx-users for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: it seems that wrapping into `\beginL...\endL` seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 0}

\usepackage[hebrew]{babel}

\begin{document}
\beginL\colorbox{shadecolor}{test}\endL
\end{document}
```

AFAICS Hebrew text in the box maintains the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your solution and it seems that Hebrew text is reversed this way, I think you need to enclose the text with `\beginR`, `\endR`. for example the following code will produce:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 0}

\usepackage[hebrew]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \beginL\colorbox{shadecolor}{שלום}\endL
    
    \beginL\colorbox{shadecolor}{\beginR שלום\endR}\endL
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a way to fix this, without the need of adding `\beginL`, `\beginR`, etc., manually (and it also fix `fcolorbox`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1, 0, 0}

\usepackage[hebrew]{babel}

\makeatletter
\long\def\color@b@x#1#2#3{%
    \leavevmode\if@rl\beginL\fi
    \setbox\z@\hbox{\kern\fboxsep{\set@color\if@rl\beginR\fi #3\if@rl\endR\fi}\kern\fboxsep}%
    \dimen@\ht\z@\advance\dimen@\fboxsep\ht\z@\dimen@
    \dimen@\dp\z@\advance\dimen@\fboxsep\dp\z@\dimen@
    {#1{#2\color@block{\wd\z@}{\ht\z@}{\dp\z@}%
            \box\z@}}\if@rl\endL\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \colorbox{shadecolor}{שלום}
    
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \colorbox{shadecolor}{Hello}
\end{document}
```

Which produce the following

[image]